# Can not find Swift Protocol declaration in Obj-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift3, swift-protocols

I have created on `Class` in `Swift` and that class and its protocol I am using in `Obj-C` enabled project but I am getting below error while compiling my project.

> cannot find protocol declaration for 'SpeechRecognizerDelegate'; did
>   you mean 'SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate'?

Can anyone guide me on this how can I use Swift class protocol in my Obj-C class.

**Here is my Swift code:**

```
protocol SpeechRecognizerDelegate : class  {
    func speechRecognitionFinished(_ transcription:String)
    func speechRecognitionError(_ error:Error)
}


class SpeechRecognizer: NSObject, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {
    open weak var delegate: SpeechRecognizerDelegate?

}
```

**Protocol use in Obj-C:**

```
#import "ARBot-Swift.h"

@interface ChatScreenViewController : JSQMessagesViewController <SpeechRecognizerDelegate>
```

Let me know if required more info.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your **Swift** protocol like this inside your Swift file.

```
@objc protocol SpeechRecognizerDelegate: class{
  func speechRecognitionFinished(_ transcription:String)
  func speechRecognitionError(_ error:Error)
}
```

*Create a Swift Module inside your project setting then use it. You can find [here complete blog](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swift-objective-c-mixed-languages-app-16b6c9c3e9b0) for the mix language coding.*

#### Then use Protocol inside Objective C class,

We required to add **protocol** inside **Objective C** file -

```
#import "ARBot-Swift.h"

@interface ChatScreenViewController : JSQMessagesViewController <SpeechRecognizerDelegate>
```

---

Then you need to conform to the **protocol** methods -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SpeechRecognizer * speechRecognizer = [[SpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
    speechRecognizer.delegate = self;
}


#pragma mark - Delegate Methods
-(void)speechRecognitionFinished:(NSString *) transcription{
   //Do something here
}

-(void)speechRecognitionError:(NSError *) error{
   //Do something here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by add protocol inside ? I am doing same with confirm protocol but getting compiler error.

Comment: You need to add Protocol methods for Protocol confirmation. Have you done this? @CodeChanger

Comment: `@objc protocol SpeechRecognizerDelegate` are you using your **protocol** like this?

Answer (score 10):

**in Swift:**

```
@objc public protocol YOURSwiftDelegate {
    func viewReceiptPhoto()
    func amountPicked(selected: Int)
}

class YourClass: NSObject {
    weak var delegat: YOURSwiftDelegate?
}
```

**in Objective-C headerFile.h**

```
@protocol YOURSwiftDelegate;

@interface YOURController : UIViewController < YOURSwiftDelegate >
```

**in Objective-C Implementation.m**

```
SwiftObject * swiftObject = [SwiftObject alloc] init];
swiftObject.delegate = self
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The key is to add the `@protocol YOURSwiftDelegate;` line in your objective C code. After that the next error will ask you to define the missing functions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after following (import header + Objc annotation on protocol). I got the warning when using Swift code from Objective C headers. Solved by only importing into the implementation .m files.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@objc` attribute to your protocol:

```
@objc protocol SpeechRecognizerDelegate : class  {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include Swift Classes in Objective-C Headers Using Forward Declarations

```
//MySwiftClass.swift
@objc protocol MySwiftProtocol {}
@objcMembers class MySwiftClass {}

// MyObjcClass.h
@class MySwiftClass;
@protocol MySwiftProtocol;

@interface MyObjcClass : NSObject
- (MySwiftClass *)returnSwiftClassInstance;
- (id <MySwiftProtocol>)returnInstanceAdoptingSwiftProtocol;
// ...
@end
```